# How to make navbar-burger menu work on small screen like iPhone using angular and bulma?

Tags: css, angular, navbar, bulma

When I click the burger menu on a small screen nothing happens. Of course, it works fine on a large screen. I have tried several  "navbar" configurations. The included code at least compiles.  I had a target defined :  class="navbar-burger is active" data-target="navbar-menu"  and an id for   class="navbar-menu" id = "navbar-menu" 
What am I missing?

```
  <!-- logo -->
  <div class="navbar-brand is-large">
  <a class="navbar-item" href="#">
      <img src="assets/img/Grayscale_cloud.png">
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-burger is active" data-target="navbar-menu">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- menu -->
  <div class="navbar-menu" id = "navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
    <a class="navbar-item" routerLink="">Home</a>
    <a class="navbar-item" routerLink="contact">Contact</a>
    <a class="navbar-item" routerLink="networksupport">Network</a>
    <a class="navbar-item" routerLink="managemnentreports">Management Reports</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

`,

I tried the code here to no avail. https://medium.com/@edigleyssonsilva/bulma-css-framework-with-angular-6-responsive-menu-and-navbar-burger-dff747ed2dc1

Several good examples here but I could not make them work with Bulma and Angular: [I'm trying to use hamburger menu on bulma css, but it doesn't work. What is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137114/im-trying-to-use-hamburger-menu-on-bulma-css-but-it-doesnt-work-what-is-wron)

Routing works as expected on a large browser. Burger menu appears on small screen but no appears when you press it.

Answer (score 3):

there are a few things which might cause this for you - since you didn't paste a MCV example, i'll list them all

- you didn't paste your toggle function for showing main-nav or burger nav... this is the toggle function (in **app.component.ts**) from the medium article link which you pasted
    `toggleNavbar() { this.navBurger.nativeElement.classList.toggle('is-active'); this.navMenu.nativeElement.classList.toggle('is-active'); }`
- to get this toggle function to work, you'd have to assign the names in **app.component.html**

  - you had `<div class="navbar-menu" id = "navbar-menu">` ... which should have `<div class="navbar-menu" id = "navbar-menu" #navMen>`
  - and `<a class="navbar-item" href="#"> .... </a>` ...which should have
    `<a (click)="toggleNavbar()" role="button" #navBurger data-target="navbar-menu"> ... </a>`
- Also, we had to do `npm install bulma`
- add the css in our angular.json:
  `"styles": ["node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.min.css" ],`

you can check a [working sample here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fh6tqa)

Comment: Thanks for the sample code.  I  am working through it  and will apply it to my code. I  could not get "styles": ["node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.min.css" ],to  complie so I  went  with     "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css",
        "styles.scss"
      ],

Comment: Your path is also valid, bulma.min.css is a little smaller in size than bulma.css; good luck !!

Comment: Akber, the site is working. Thank you for your wisdom and knowledge.- Ross Mason

Comment: Hi Ross, I'm glad that it helped. please mark the answer as accepted and vote it up so that others can find it useful also... happy coding :)